# where is the syntax error in this two query used together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Code runs in *phpmyadmin* but not running in my php code and says the code has syntax problem. 
What is the problem ?

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ( 'test' , 'test@email.com' , '13456'); 
UPDATE `users` SET `email`='test2@email.com'
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `users` SET `email`='test2@email.com'' at line 1 (SQL: INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ( 'test' , 'test@email.com' , '13456'); UPDATE `users` SET `email`='test2@email.com')

Comment: You likely need to execute the INSERT and UPDATE as 2 separate SQL statements in PHP.

Comment: actually i am making a php code with bugs for educational security tests the users should write code like this to solve this question as you said they can not write a code like this unless i search their queries and run them in separate executions ?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a SQL shell. PDO and such are SQL drivers. They behave in different ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run two queries from PHP in one call, unless you use `mysqli_multi_query()`. Split them into two separate calls.